# $f(x) = 2x \mod 1$ not equal to zero for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, chaos-theory

If any number $\mod 1$ is zero, then how can $f(x) = 2x \mod 1$ be a Baker's map? For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, shouldn't $f(x)=0$?

Comment: You say "any number mod 1" is zero.  Perhaps you are thinking about any **integer** mod 1.  In the above, is $x$ only taking integer values?  Or can $x$ take real values as well?  You have things like $53.712 \equiv 0.712\not\equiv 0\pmod{1}$.  You can think of modulo $1$ similarly as taking the fractional part of a number.  In the case of integers, there is no nonzero fractional part, but for real numbers there can be.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of integers for some reason. Now it's clear :)